# iOS Swift Xcode 6 separation of concerns for view controller delegates in storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1

I'm having a lot of fun learning iOS dev and Swift, but having a spot of bother with this.

I'm writing a view with a bunch of controls in it, and my UIViewController is getting a bit bloated with all the delegate protocols it has to support. So I want to break out some of the delegation to separate classes. But there doesn't seem to be any way of connecting the view controls to the separated classes in the storyboard?

Example: I did have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
  ...code...
}
```

and it was easy to connect the picker view to this by dragging the connectors to the ViewController thingy in the top margin of the view in the storyboard, like so:
[image: dragging the connectors to the ViewController thingy in the top margin of the view]

now I have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
 ...code...
}
```

and in a separate file:

```
class PickerHandler: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
  ...code...
}
```

However, there's no way I can drag the delegate connectors for the picker view to this class, so how do I wire up the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answers: Like snowman4415.

Swift recommended way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 ...code...
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {
}
```

You can put these extensions anywhere you want. There is no need to make another class for this, assuming you just don't want your class becomes too big.

Also, there are other cases that require making another class, like you did, but it requires more works, like when you have to write extra `protocol` in order to delegate from `PickerHandler` back to `ViewController` (because you can't call `ViewController`'s instance inside `PickerHandler` class directly)

Comment: excellent, thanks for the answer, this makes sense for tidying up my code base :)